# Rotation resolutions in operations for qubits in commercial implementations

Tags: quantum-operation

I have found information about Honeywell provider supporting operations with high-resolution rotations (i.e. around $\pi/500$) [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/quantum/provider-honeywell).

What are typical maximal rotation resolution values supported by existing implementations and what is their usefulness in algorithms?